# Runtime split our the line based on moving nearest vertex in pgrouting?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I attached my screenshot using pgrouting.

Is it possible to runtime split our the line based on moving nearest vertex in pgrouting?

Is there any easiest function or solution over there?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PostGIS function to snap point on the nearest road/line.

1. Query geom_1 requested point/current location with a geom_2 polyline/road with SQL query,
2. Post back results to the app from the SQL query.

Use `ST_Snap`:

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html

If you want to get a line intersection point, then try`ST_ClosestPoint`:

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html